# How to prevent css3 animation reset when finished?

Tags: css, css-animations

I write a css3 animation and it is only performed once. The animation works well, but it will reset when the animation finished. How can I avoid this, I want to keep the result instead of reset it.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fdiv").delay(1000).addClass("go");
});
```

```css
#fdiv {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.go {
  -webkit-animation: spinAndZoom 1s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinAndZoom {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fdiv"></div>
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KCbFf/).

Comment: People from the future, please, don't use any vendor prefix from those answers. If your target browser still require those then use an automated tool to put those, like [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

to your `.go`

> The animation’s final keyframe continues to apply after the final iteration of the animation completes.

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-animation-fill-mode

Answer (score 5):

Add the following style to your stylesheet:

```
.go {
     /* Already exists */
     -webkit-animation: spinAndZoom 1s 1;

     /*New content */
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Add animation-fill-mode: forwards;

```
.go {
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }
```