# How to prevent animation reset after a rotation?

Tags: html, css

I have already visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296919/how-to-prevent-css3-animation-reset-when-finished) question. However, `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` does not seem to prevent a reset after a rotation animation.

This code results in the span reverting to its normal state after the rotation is complete:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin
{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); }
}

.spin:hover span
{
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

But, this code, which is not a rotation, works:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shove
{
    0%   { margin-left: 0px; }
    100% { margin-left: 50px; }
}

.shove:hover span
{
    -webkit-animation: shove 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52KN7/13/) to take a look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. For some reason the rotation animation resets if the element is `inline`. By displaying the `span` as a `block` or `inline-block` the animation does not reset after the rotation.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52KN7/18/) demonstrating the answer.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.spin {
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s linear;
}

.spin:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52KN7/17/