# css transition opacity is not working where element had display:none then changed to display:block

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like the title said. I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/fwo9ym1o/

```
//javascript
    var container = document.querySelector("#container");

    container.style.display = "block";

    //this is not working
    //container.style.opacity = 1;


    //this is working
    setTimeout(function() {
       container.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 0);

/css
    .container {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: salmon;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    }

//html
    <div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

So, I've changed the `container.style.display = "block";` then applied `container.style.opacity = 1;` and the transition is not happening.

It works if I run everything in a new thread.

**NOTE: I can't use visibility. It has to be display:none**

Comment: _"and the transition is not happening"_  The expected result is returned at jsfiddle at chromium and firefox. Which browsers did you try `css`, `javascript` at?

Comment: it works if I use setTimout if you uncomment that it's not working

Comment: What is issue with using `setTimeout`?

Comment: none. just that I try to avoid using setTimeout and was curious why is not working without that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the way styles are figured out. Style changes are expensive so they are effectively saved up until they are needed (a recalc check like `.offsetHeight` is called or the next frame needs to be drawn).

The following code should work. It includes an explanation of what (I think) is going on:

```
container.style.display = "block";
// container is actually still invisible
// current style hasn't been calculated

container.offsetHeight;
// this forces a style recalc
// so the current style for the container is figured out.
// without this recalc, this element effectively has no style,
// and so when you transition from its current style (null) to a different one (opacity: 1), it just snaps to the new value.

container.style.opacity = 1;
// this triggers the transition.
// because the style was recalced before the transition was triggered,
// it will transition _from_ those values.
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwo9ym1o/4/)

Comment: thanks, Already found something similar using getComputedStyle(container).opacity;

Comment: Oh. That just gives you the latest style. I guess it would do the same thing, but I would guess it'd be more expensive. Up to you.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat This answer got me out of trouble too. In my case, I triggered a CSS transition by setting an attribute. The sequence became, briefly,  `container.style.display='block'; container.offsetHeight; container.setAttribute(someting,'')`. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: What would be the jQuery equivalent for this? I've tried `$('#my_element').offsetHeight;` but it doesn't seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest you use `animation` instead, it is much more appropriate than force a redraw.

```js
var container = document.querySelector("#container");
container.classList.add('animateme');
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.animateme {
  display: block;
  animation: animate 2s linear;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the marked 'right' answer I vote for the answer [from LGSon above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39549562/6597265) due to it being not a workaround but using natural CSS capability.

Plus it gives a cleaner code in JS due to the ease of toggling a class (`container.classList.toggle('animateme')`) and separation of concerns (JS does not manipulate CSS properties directly).

However I experienced the animation `animate` getting reset at the end to its zero keyframe i.e. to `opacity: 0`;

To make it stay I added `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to `.animateme` selector like this (taken from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17297042/6597265))

```
.animateme {
  display: block;
  animation: animate 2s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var container = document.querySelector("#container");
container.style.opacity = 1;

<div id="container" class="container"></div>

.container {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: salmon;
display: block;
border-radius: 5px;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o85ne4x3/)

Comment: thanks. but like the title said. container need to be display:none in the begining.