# Change display from block to none, then fade in

Tags: javascript, css

I am moving through form sections by setting display none/block and fade in/out.  On "p1" button click I can fade out element "Q1" & display:none, display:block "Q2" - but I can never get Q2 to fade in.  It shows up with full opacity, but never with a transition.

I have tried not using display at all, instead height from 0 to 100%, but still no transition with opacity.  I have tried using this with css components and changing the style class, still no opacity transition on Q2.

```
const Q1 = document.getElementById("Q1");
const Q2 = document.getElementById("Q2");
const p1 = document.getElementById("p1");

Q1.style.display = "block";
Q1.style.opacity = 100;
Q1.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s";

Q2.style.display = "none";
Q2.style.opacity = 0;
Q2.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s";

const f_fade1 = (() => { Q1.style.opacity = 0; });
const hide_1 = (() => { Q1.style.display = "none"; });
const unhide_2 = (() => { Q2.style.display = "block"; });
const f_unfade2 = (() => { Q2.style.opacity = 1; });

p1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     f_fade1();
     Q1.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
        hide_1();
        unhide_2();
        f_unfade2();

      });
      });
```

```
<div id="Q1">
<table>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1A" name="radio1" value="Agressive">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Aggressive<br>(99)</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 1000%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>55%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1B" name="radio1" value="Agressive/Moderate">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Moderate/Aggressive<br>(97-98)</td>
        <td>80%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 80%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>45%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1C" name="radio1" value="Moderate">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Moderate<br>(93-96)</td>
        <td>60%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 60%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>35%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1D" name="radio1" value="Moderate/Conservative">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Moderate/Conservative<br>(85-92)</td>
        <td>40%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 40%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>28%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1E" name="radio1" value="Conservative">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Conservative<br>(51-84)</td>
        <td>20%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 20%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>20%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1F" name="radio1" value="Fixed Income">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Fixed Income<br>(1-50)</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 0%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>10%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<div id="Q2">
<table>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="2A" name="radio2" value="Core 0%/Explore 100%">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#00108E 0%, #1089FF 0); align:center;"></div>
        </td>
        <td> 0%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="2B" name="radio2" value="Core 25%/Explore 75%">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td> 75%</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#00108E 25%, #1089FF 0); align:center;"></div>
        </td>
        <td> 25%</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>

<button id="p1" type="button">Page 2 Next</button>
```

I am currently using no css specific to Q1 or Q2 (just table stuff)

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/rcbjmbadb/pen/BaapKPR) - you can see how the fade out / display works fine, just not the fade in

Comment: Can you please post some of the HTML? And any initial CSS. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Akshit Mehra I don't want it to take up space, so if I used visibility, I would also have to adjust the height.  I actually tried both, and still couldn't get the 2nd transition to work.

Comment: @Akshit Mehra So far, position: absolute doesn't work well well with my other table properties.  I may try to work this out later if there are no other ideas.

Comment: @disinfor I added html, and a codepen to demonstrate my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `display` from `block` to `none` also changes the opacity for some reason. Because Q2 is already hidden with the opacity set to 0 there is not need to change set the display value.

Setting initial `display` value of Q2 to `block` and not changing the display value will give you the expect result.

```js
const Q1 = document.getElementById("Q1");
 const Q2 = document.getElementById("Q2");
 const p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
  
 Q1.style.display = "block";
 Q1.style.opacity = 100;
 Q1.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s";
  
 Q2.style.display = "none";
 Q2.style.opacity = 0;
 Q2.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s";
  
 const f_fade1 = (() => { Q1.style.opacity = 0; });
 const hide_1 = (() => { Q1.style.display = "none"; });
 const unhide_2 = (() => { Q2.style.display = "block"; Q2.offsetHeight; });
 const f_unfade2 = (() => { Q2.style.opacity = 1; });
  
 p1.addEventListener("click", e => {
    f_fade1();
    Q1.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
      hide_1();
      unhide_2();
      f_unfade2();
    });
 });
```

```html
<div id="Q1">
  <table>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
          <label class="container">
              <input type="radio" id="1A" name="radio1" value="Agressive">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
      </td>
      <td>Aggressive<br>(99)</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>
          <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 1000%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
      </td>
      <td>55%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
        <label class="container">
          <input type="radio" id="1B" name="radio1" value="Agressive/Moderate">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>Moderate/Aggressive<br>(97-98)</td>
      <td>80%</td>
      <td>
        <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 80%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
      </td>
      <td>45%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
        <label class="container">
          <input type="radio" id="1C" name="radio1" value="Moderate">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>Moderate<br>(93-96)</td>
      <td>60%</td>
      <td>
        <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 60%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
      </td>
      <td>35%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
        <label class="container">
            <input type="radio" id="1D" name="radio1" value="Moderate/Conservative">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>Moderate/Conservative<br>(85-92)</td>
      <td>40%</td>
      <td>
        <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 40%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
      </td>
      <td>28%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
        <label class="container">
            <input type="radio" id="1E" name="radio1" value="Conservative">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>Conservative<br>(51-84)</td>
      <td>20%</td>
      <td>
        <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 20%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
      </td>
      <td>20%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
        <label class="container">
            <input type="radio" id="1F" name="radio1" value="Fixed Income">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>Fixed Income<br>(1-50)</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>
        <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 0%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
      </td>
      <td>10%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
    
    
<div id="Q2">
  <table>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
        <label class="container">
          <input type="radio" id="2A" name="radio2" value="Core 0%/Explore 100%">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#00108E 0%, #1089FF 0); align:center;"></div>
      </td>
      <td> 0%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
      <td>
        <label class="container">
          <input type="radio" id="2B" name="radio2" value="Core 25%/Explore 75%">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </td>
        <td> 75%</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#00108E 25%, #1089FF 0); align:center;"></div>
        </td>
        <td> 25%</td>
      </tr>   
  </table>
</div>
    
<button type="button" id="p1">Click me</button>
```

Comment: It works, but I need the height of Q2 to also not be shown, without the display set to "none" it gives me the blank space that Q2 takes up.

Comment: In that case you need do call `Q2.offsetHeight` of Q2 after you change it the display value to `block`. I've updated my anwser. More info can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548684/css-transition-opacity-is-not-working-where-element-had-displaynone-then-change

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:** Please see what I suggested [here at CodePen](https://codepen.io/akshitmehra/pen/BaapKgw?editors=1010). It works.

I don't have the permission to comment here, but why don't you use `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`, instead of changing the `display` property?

The `opacity` property shall remain as it is.

You can also add `position: absolute` along with the `visibility: hidden` property to simulate `display: none` effect. And then change back the `position` to `static`.

Comment: @rcbjmbadb I just edited the answer to include `position: absolute`. Let me know if this helps? I am not able to reply to your comment on the question.

Comment: @rcbjmbadb You can try the CodePen I added. It solves the issue of blank space that Q2 takes.